# How can enable/disable navigation tab with ifconfig condition -magento2

Tags: magento2, frontend, customer-account

**In my custom tab from customer navigation**,

I have added two blocks from two different custom modules.

**I have added configuration for both to enable and disable but how can I remove that custom tab link only when both modules are disabled?**

How can we add condition with **ifconfig** from xml or is there any other way to do it?

Comment: I have the similar question over here. We have 2 different modules let's say "Module A" and "Module B".

We have to display single link in account dashboard but having two different sections from each module in same page.

We wanted to add condition "ifconfig" with and cause if both module is enable.

Comment: @Keith Are you talking about customer  setction custom tab in admin panel?

Comment: In frontend, custom tab link is in customer navigation